# Assignment within Spark Scala foreach Loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to scala/spark and am trying to loop through a dataframe and assign the results as the loop progresses. The following code works but can only print the results to screen.

```
traincategory.columns.foreach { x=>

val test1 = traincategory.select("Id", x)

import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{OneHotEncoder, StringIndexer}

//CODE TO PERFORM ONEHOT TRANSFORMATION

val encoded = encoder.transform(indexed)

encoded.show()

}
```

As val is immutable I have attempted to append the vectors from this transformation onto another variable, as might be done in R.

```
//var ended = traincategory.withColumn(x,encoded(0))
```

I suspect Scala has a more idiomatic way of processing this.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you looked at the Spark documentation ? https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-features.html#onehotencoder

Answer (score 0):

A solution was available at :

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/Correlations.scala

If anyone has similar issues with Scala MLIB  there is great example code at :

https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib